# Swift Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when I try to change a uilabel.text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I know there are a lot of Stack Overflow questions like this out there, but none of the answers I can find work for me. I am using a custom `UITableViewCell` class called `chillerCell`. Here is its code:

```
import UIKit

class chillerCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var iconLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var boldLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var italicLabel: UILabel!

    func configureCellWithEvent(event: Event){
        boldLabel.text = "\(event.eventName)"
        italicLabel.text = "\(event.eventDescription)"
    }
}
```

I get the **Thread 1 runtime error** on the line `boldLabel.text = "\(event.eventName)"`

I made my own `Event` class, and yes, `event.eventName` and `event.eventDescription` are of type `String` and are not `Nil`.

Edit: I forgot to mention, my boldLabel and italicLabel are not plain text, but attributed text.

Comment: Can you give us more detail of the runtime error? Have you checked that your IBOutlet is correctly linked?

Comment: Yes my storyboard is connected properly. I even disconnected the outlets and reconnected them.

Comment: Very strange. Can you check boldLabel in the debugger to ensure it is not nil. If not try changing another property - e.g. BoldLabel.hidden = true. Also try swapping boldLabel and italicLabel to see if it is specific to boldLabel.

Comment: boldLabel is nil. However, it is definitely connected to the storyboard

Comment: OK, but that sounds like the problem. Take a look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223457/reasons-for-an-iboutlet-to-be-nil) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321383/iboutlet-is-nil-but-it-is-connected-in-storyboard-swift) to find out why a linked Outlet may still be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it would work if event object having eventName & eventDescription as String:

```
func configureCellWithEvent(event: Event){
    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"(event.eventName)") and boldLabel.text = attributedString
    boldLabel.text = attributedString
    italicLabel.text = attributedString
}
```

Comment: Can you copy-paste your event object values here?

Comment: And just to double check the IBOutlet connection, just check if this works for you. func configureCellWithEvent(event: Event){
    boldLabel.text = "Test Bold Label"
    italicLabel.text = "Test Italic Label"
}

Comment: I just tried the test values and I still got an error

Comment: So here is the bug then, your IBOutlet connections are broken. Fix that in your storyboard. Go to storyboard and click on label to check or create new IBOutlet using ctrl+drag from UILabel to the class.

Comment: My IBOutlets are fine, I reset them and I still get an error

Comment: However, both labels are attributed text and not plain text

Comment: I updated my answer. okkay, then try this. var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(event.eventName)") and boldLabel.text = attributedString

Comment: It won't let me, so I tried `boldLabel.attributedText` and it still gives me the Thread 1 error

Answer (score 0):

Delete the labels and create a others again, thats work for me.